# PHPUnit - get test pass status + name in tearDown()

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

In PHPUnit, how can I get info in tearDown() if my test passed or not, and what its name?
I've tried looking into `$this->getTestResultObject()->topTestSuite()`, but not luck - tests seem like they are fresh with no ok/failure in them.

As output I want my custom tearDown() to have something like:

```
TESTCLASSNAME::TESTMETHOD - ok
TESTCLASSNAME::TESTMETHOD2 - failed
```

Answer (score 3):

Class name = `explode('::',$this->toString())[0]`

Test name = `$this->getName()`

Status = `$this->hasFailed()`